# Solving ode which solution oscillate violently

Tags: differential-equations

This is a ordinary differential equation:

```
y[x]/(-1 + x^4)^2 - ((1 + 2 x^2 + 3 x^4 - 2 x^6) Derivative[1][y][x])/(x - x^5) + Derivative[2][y][x] == 0
```

I want to solve this equation numerically, so I investigate the asymptotic solution of the equation. The asymptotic form of the equation near the point x=1 is:

```
(1/(16*(x - 1)^2))*y[x] + (1/(x - 1))*Derivative[1][y][x] + Derivative[2][y][x] == 0
```

I can solve the asymptotic form analytically:

```
DSolve[(1/(16*(x - 1)^2))*y[x] + (1/(x - 1))*Derivative[1][y][x] + Derivative[2][y][x] == 0, y, x]
```

The asymptotic solution is:

```
{{y -> Function[{x}, C[1]*Cos[(1/4)*Log[4 - 4*x]] -  C[2]*Sin[(1/4)*Log[4 - 4*x]]]}}
```

Then I select the boundary conditions to solve the equation numerically:

```
yb1[x_] := 1; yb2[x_] := (1 - x)^(-(I/4));
sol1[\[Epsilon]_] := NDSolve[{y[x]/(-1 + x^4)^2 - ((1 + 2*x^2 + 3*x^4 - 2*x^6)*Derivative[1][y][x])/(x - x^5) + Derivative[2][y][x] == 0, y[\[Epsilon]] == yb1[\[Epsilon]], y[1 - \[Epsilon]] == yb2[1 - \[Epsilon]]},y, {x, \[Epsilon], 1 - \[Epsilon]}]
```

Because the coefficient of the equation is singular at the point x=0 and x=1, so I have to add a small value epsilon.
The above statement can be carry out in Mathematica, but I find the solution is sensitive to the value of epsilon. The following statement plot the solution at different value of epsilon:

```
  Plot[{Re[y[x1]] /. sol1[10^-5][[1]], Re[y[x1]] /. sol1[10^-4][[1]],Re[y[x1]] /. sol1[10^-3][[1]]}, {x1, 0.01, 1}]
```

You can see that the solution is very sensitive to the value of epsilon. I think the problem is attribute to the solution that oscillate violently near the point x=1. What can I do to solve this equation numerically?